# XAML - C# - picture in MenuItem is not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, icons, menuitem

I am not able to display picture in MenuItem.

In XAML designer it's correctly show, but whenever I run the program, it's not there.

```
<MenuItem Header="_Nová kalkulace" Click="NewCalculation_Click">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="/graphics/icons/new.png" Height="20" Width="20" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

The picture Build Action is set to Content (I also tried Resource, but without effect).

[Screen of XAML designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXMxU.png)

Any hint? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why, but after setting Action Build to Resource and Cleaning/Building sollution, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<MenuItem Header="_Nová kalkulace" Click="NewCalculation_Click">
<MenuItem.Icon>
  <Image Height="20" Width="20" Source="pack://application:,,,/your_assembly;component/graphics/icons/new.png"/>
</MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

or

```
<MenuItem>
<MenuItem.Icon>
<Image>
  <Image.Source>
    <BitmapImage UriSource="/your_assembly;component/graphics/icons/new.png" />
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I have some issues with message: Could not find a part of the path 'd:\AssemblyInfo.cs;component\graphics\icons\new.png'. I will try to google it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always set source in Property window `Press (F4)`. This will automatically set required arguments for source property.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the "Copy to Output" Setting? Usually this should be set to "Copy if newer" or "always copy".

Comment: Yes, I have it in picture setting.